# Send photos to a Bot telegram with Rundeck

Tags: automation, telegram, photo, rundeck

I'm using Rundeck for some automation and i already use it to send messages with a bot to a specific Telegram Grops.

I do it using a

`"HTTP Request Step" with "https://api.telegram.org/<BOT>/sendMessage"`

and 2 input options

`{ "chat_id": "${option.chatid}",  "text": "${option.corpo}" }`
It works perfectly!

Now I'm trying to evolve it sending photos with:

`https://api.telegram.org/<BOT>/sendPhoto`  And this 3 input options
`{ "chat_id": "${option.chatid}", "text": "${option.corpo}", "file": "${file.file}" }`

The file option is a "File" type.

the error that appears is:

`{ "ok": false, "error_code": 400, "description": "Bad Request: there is no photo in the request" } Error when sending request: Attempted read from closed stream.`

Do you have some tips?
Thank you!

Miglio

I've tried to use "photo" and not "file" in the body of the option, but it doesn't works.

Comment: Have you tried using a curl call on a Rundeck script step? You can try first from your terminal, This is a good way to troubleshoot this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. The [`sendPhoto`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) method does not have a `file` paramater, you'll need to pass the photo to the `photo` parameter.
2. There is also no `text` parameter, that's called `caption` on `sendPhoto`

---

Not an rundeck expect but seems like you'll need something like:

- `file` → `photo`
- `text` → `caption`

```
{ "chat_id": "${option.chatid}", "caption": "${option.corpo}", "photo": "${file.file}" }
```